# how to redirect multi parameter url using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My old url is

http://www.tuitionok.com/result.php?sr=0&city=patna&text=computer+home+tuition+in+patna&type=home-tuition#t

and new url is

http://www.tuitionok.com/patna/home-tuition/computer-home-tuition-in-patna/0

I am trying to forward the old url to new

I am using this .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ result.php?city=$1&type=$2&text=$3&sr=$4 [L]
```

I am successfully get the parameter values and displaying the result. But the actual problem is that both old and new url is working. I think my htaccess file should be modified to redirect url forcely to the new url.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ result.php?city=$1&type=$2&text=$3&sr=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ result.php?city=$1&type=$2&text=$3&sr=$4 [L]
```

Comment: it is not redirecting to new url

Comment: You have to change the variables value having space by hypen like $type = str_replace(' ','-', $type);

Comment: there is no space in variable i also used this url http://www.tuitionok.com/result.php?sr=0&city=patna&text=computer-home-tuition-in-patna&type=home-tuition#t but not redirecting

Comment: Can you show the php code so i can understand what you actually doing?

Comment: here is the query code in php $query="select * from organisation where type='$type' and display=1 and $city like '%$city%' and keyword like '%$text%' limit $sr, 10";

Comment: You have to create links by replacing space by hypen and you have to get data from database again by replacing hypen to space by using str_replace php function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php